# Expected mean square of random effect in CRD model

Tags: self-study, random-effects-model

Random effect in CRD model:

\begin{align}
y_{ij}           &= \mu + \tau_{i} + \varepsilon_{ij}  \\
\tau_{i}         &\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_{\tau}^2)   \\
\varepsilon_{ij} &\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)
\end{align}

I want to prove

$$
E(MStr)=\sigma^2+n\sigma_{\tau}^2
$$

The following is what I have done so far:

$\text{Let }i = 1, \ldots, p,\quad\quad j = 1, \ldots,n.$

\begin{align}
E(\overline{y_{i.}}) &= E\bigg(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{ij}}{n}\bigg) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}E(\mu+\tau_{i}+\varepsilon_{ij})}{n} = \mu+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\tau_{i}}{n}  \\
\ \\
  &= \mu+\overline{\tau_{i}}  \\
\ \\
E(\overline{y_{..}}) &= E\bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{ij}}{np}\bigg) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E(\mu+\tau_{i}+\varepsilon_{ij})}{np}  \\
\ \\
  &= \mu+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\overline{\tau_{i}}}{p}  \\
\ \\
E(MStr) &= \sigma^{2}+\frac{n\sum_{i=1}^{p}(E(\overline{y_{i.}})-E(\overline{y_{..}}))^2}{p-1} = \sigma^{2}+\frac{n\sum_{i=1}^{p}\big(\overline{\tau_{i}}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p}\overline{\tau_{i}}}{p}\big)^2}{p-1}  \\
\ \\
      &= \sigma^2+n\sigma_{\overline{\tau}}^2
\end{align}

Could anyone help me find the mistakes I made?

Comment: You jump into your question with no context or explanation of the terminology. This will make it unintelligible except to anyone who might have chanced across your reference (or those who like to make educated guesses about what the notation might mean).  Please edit your question to make it generally understandable.  Thank you!